# could not load image

Tags: html, css

I am using map image

```
<div class="map" style="background-image:url(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=17.4542,78.36427000000003&amp;zoom=15&amp;size=1000x1000&amp;sensor=false&amp;markers=color:blue%7C17.4542,78.36427000000003&amp;scale=2);"></div>
```

But it is not displaying in browser

Comment: The URL of the image is missing something. Google answers with: "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'size' parameter.".

Comment: remove all amp; from your URL

Comment: is that an image? isnt it an `api` response?

Comment: image with dynamic lat and longitudes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is incorrect, you need to remove all **amp;** from your URL Like this :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=17.4542,78.36427000000003&zoom=15&size=1000x1000&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7C17.4542,78.36427000000003&scale=2